# Binding same field into two columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind data from one field to gridview, but in gridview it must be displayed as two column, how can I make it possible? Can anybody help me..

Comment: Why dont add just two columns with same datafield?

Comment: What does it mean.do you want to split the one field value as two fields.??If yes.You can handle it in code level(.cs)

Comment: @mshsayem if I add two columns then data will repeat, I want the continuation of first column data

Comment: @Shankar Parshimoni ya I want to split one field value as two fields

Comment: Explain your db table design and sample data, and sample output you are expecting. You can just do this stuff in excel, take screen shots, and put it out here...

Comment: Then how do you want the other fields to be shown? Or, has the datasource only a single field?

Comment: @mshsayem ya only one field to show but shown as two column

Comment: An idea: Use a `Repeater`; Use `float:left` on the items' style; adjust width so that only 2 item can appear in a row (say 45% of parent container)

Comment: @mshsayem ok let me try thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Repeater having `float` (with < 50% width) on item style you can achieve something like that.

**markup**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMyData">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="float:left;width: 45%">
            <%# Eval("MyField") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```